# Make app support action_send only for custom file extension

Tags: android, action, send, mime

I save some objects from my app as files with a custom file extension (.xyz) that can be saved to other apps. Now once I have such a file on dropbox for example and try to export it, it should show my app. Right now the only way to make it show my app, is to make it accept any mime type like:

```
  <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
```

How do I make it that my app will be an option only if the file ends with .xyz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible in general.

If the file extension corresponds to a well-known MIME type (e.g., [`MimeTypeMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) knows about it), you can modify your `android:mimeType` to use that MIME type.

But file extensions themselves are not going to be used with `ACTION_SEND` due to the way the `Uri` gets packaged in the `Intent` (as an extra, rather than as part of the "data"). Plus, more often, you will get a `content` `Uri`, not a `file` `Uri`, and a `content` `Uri` may not even *have* a file extension, let alone the right one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation